# Why ToString using "." operator

Tags: c#, class, operators

Im starting the second course in computer programming and right now I have an intermediate level of C language knowledge, beginner C++ and just have started learning C# language. In  C# fundamentals by Bob Tabor he uses the . as class operator eg.

```
Console.WriteLine(myValue); Console.ReadLine();
```

Where Console is the class and WriteLine is part of this class. To keep everything organised I was trying understand all the concepts of it but in one moment he converted an integer to string by using function:

```
myValue.ToString();
```

And in that point I got lost. Why he uses that logic instead of simple and organised way like:

```
System.ToString(MyValue);
```

He hasn't used the value that has to be converted as an argument. That just doesn't make any logic sense.. Am I wrong?

Comment: What is `System.ToString(MyValue)`?

Comment: Why? If you ask why, you're gonna have a fun time if you end up learning Java :p The reason that seems obvious to me is: less verbosity.

Comment: just the idea of concept. It's just the way I would think to type it.

Comment: Okay. I got it. Just the method. Thanks everyone! I'm bad in learning stuff >_<

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every object inherits from `System.Object` (except `object` itself) in the .NET Framework. And `System.Object` defines a public `ToString()` method, therefore you can call `ToString()` on any object.

`Console.WriteLn` calls `ToString` on objects passed to it as argument, in order to get a string it can print.

There is no such thing as `System.ToString()`. `System` is a namespace and a method cannot exist in the global scope; it is always a member of a type. From within an object you can call the members directly, from outside you must use the dot syntax: `someObject.SomeMethod();` or `x = someObject.SomeProperty;`. Static members are called from the type name: `SomeType.SomeMethod();`. `Console.WriteLn();` is a good example.

Answer (score 1):

The only functional difference is that `Convert.ToString()` handles null, while `ToString()` doesn't, since `obj.ToString()` presumes the `obj` is not null, whereas `ToString(obj)` will return `String.Empty` on a `null` object.

Comment: Hey, you're gonna confuse him by introducing `Convert.ToString` amongst the others :p

Comment: Haha, maybe =P But at the same time, this difference is actually important!

Comment: why it made up to handle null instead of value as argument?

Comment: You have to explain that System is a namespace and not a class,  so you can't even call ToString on that..

Answer (score 0):

Every object has methods and properties, you call the method "ToString" to format the object as an string.

If you realize you are writting less than calling a system method to formart it.